# Windows CMD Search and Delete file by name

Tags: windows, file, cmd, delete-file

I have a website dump which has about half a gig worth of images which have been converted to various file sizes. The structure goes like:

```
media/
   1/
      1.original.jpg
      1.large.jpg
      1.medium.jpg
      1.small.jpg
   2/
      2.original.jpg
      2.large.jpg
      2.medium.jpg
      2.small.jpg
etc...
```

I want a command that will search through all folders in media and delete any image which has `original` in the name. Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe [this answer to "Recursively delete 0KB files using windows cmd" helps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4177169/205233)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
del /s ...\media\*original*.jpg
```

should delete all files with `original` in their name, extension `.jpg` from `...\media` and all its subdirectories.

Obviously, use with extreme caution...
If you desire to see what you are going to delete first before deleting it use

```
dir /s ...\media\*original*.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with something like this:

```
for /R C:\...\media %f in (*original*.jpg) do del /q "%~ff"
```

Replace `%` with `%%` if you want to use this in a batch script.