# Can I shut down echo for this "for" cycle inputed from cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd

I was trying to use [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4177169/2436175).

Is there a way to have ONE command line that executes the following (delete all files of size zero) without printing any output?

```
for /r %F in (*) do if %~zF==0 del "%F"
```

(It shows all the expanded commands, also when the size is not zero)

I have tried to use [How to redirect stderr to null in cmd.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507312/how-to-redirect-stderr-to-null-in-cmd-exe), (trying >, 1> and 2>) with no avail...

Comment: You are asking how to do "@echo off" but on one line with the command? Why?

Comment: @doctorlove Most likely, yes. Because I do not want to create a batch file to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`@` suppresses the output for one command. So the following does what you want:

```
for /r %F in (*) do @if %~zF==0 @del "%F"
```

To show (only) the files that were deleted:

```
for /r %F in (*) do @if %~zF==0 del "%F" & echo removed %F
```

Comment: @Joey the `@` you added does not seem to be necessary, as in general del has no output (it wouldn't be an advantage, but it does not even suppress error messages -> trying to delete locked files).

Comment: To print the delete commands that will be effectively executed: `for /r %F in (*) do @if %~zF==0 echo "del %F" && del %F`

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off && for /r %F in (*) do if %~zF==0 del "%F" > NUL
```

The `> NUL` is because I can't recall if certain situations cause `del` to try to output

Comment: See my conversation with doctorlove above

Comment: @Antonio Right okay, in which case my updated answer should be what you're after

Comment: @Antonio Yea, of course if you wanted it back on just change the end to `> NUL && @echo on `